# Bootstrap Popover + Meteor JS click event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to fire a meteor event by clicking on a button inside a bootstrap popover window. However, the event is not getting fired.

Here is my code:

```
   <button name="newLetter" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus newLetter" type="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"></button>
   <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn btn-success btn-xs addNewLetter'></button>
   </div>
```

```js
Template.templateName.events({
    'click .newLetter': function(e, t) {
        $(".newLetter").popover({
           html: true,
           title: 'New Letter',
           content: function() {
              return $("#popover-content").html();
           }
       });
    },
    'click .addNewLetter': function(e, t) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First with your code, this doesn't show the popup on the first click. What you should do:

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
    $(".newLetter").popover({
        html: true,
        title: 'New Letter',
        content: function() {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    });
}
```

If you check with your debugger, you will see that each time you click on the .newLetter button, bootstrap take the content of #popover-content and place it in a new div with a class .popover. If you want to see how to bind an event on dynamically created elements, [you should check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). (the solution is to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

Now, for what is happening, Meteor is binding a click event on .addNewLetter inside #popover-content and not on the dynamically created element .addNewLetter inside the div.popover, that's why it is not working. One workaround I found:

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.addNewLetter', function() {
        console.log('hey');
    });
}
```

Comment: One question: why I am not able to get the text from the text area in the popover? I tried it this way: `var letterName = $('[name="letterName"]').val();`. I always get an empty value.

Comment: Try this and tell me: var letterName = $('textarea[name="letterName"]')[1].val();

Comment: Unfortunately: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function. Maybe it is because I have more than one text area? Or is this a meteor issue? Merci beaucoup d'avance.

Comment: Yes, check your chrome debugger, bootstrap takes what is inside #popover-content and put it in a new div.popover (and this for each click). So you get one new textarea each time you click on .newLetter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The thing is: I have multiple buttons that should show a popover with a text area. Then, I want to process the user input. Do you think this is "possible" with a popover?

Comment: Yes of course. Just a find a way to target the textarea and get its value. [Check this link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) and the $().popover(options). Maybe it can help you to fix your issue.